# How can I list songs details to be store on server

Tags: android, mysql, listview, media

Actually I am accessing the song details in a list view and now I want to store them on my server (whole list items). I'm new to Android. Please help me.

I have made the php web service which takes json

Required input:

```
$inputJSON = '{
    "currentTimeStamp" : 1446786632.036515,
    "songData" : [
        {
            "SongID" : "2",
            "status" : "1",
            "albumTitle" : "Zid",
            "playbackDuration" : 289.802,
            "artist" : "Sharib-Toshi, Sunidhi Chauhan, Sharib Sabri",
            "podcastTitle" : "Zid",
            "assetURL" : "ipod-library:\/\/item\/item.mp3?id=4206809166388889270",
            "isSelected" : "1",
            "albumArtist" : "Sharib-Toshi",
            "title" : "Tu Zaroori (Duet) - WapLoft.`enter code here`Com"
        }
    ],
    "UserID" : "2"
}';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cursor then you will have to run through the cursor and create a JSON Array of song Data.

First create a JSONArray as follows

```
JSONArray songArray= new JSONArray();
```

now put all your songs in the array as you would do in any array

```
songsArray.put(eachSongsJsonObject);
```

where

```
eachSongsJsonObject = new JSONObject();
eachSongsJsonObject.put("SongID",<the song id you got from cursor>);
eachSongsJsonObject,put("albumTitle",<album title>);
```

and so on until you get all the data. Once all that is done and your Json array is done create the master JSONobject to send as below

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONOBject();
jsonObject.put("songData",songArray);
jsonObject.put("currentTimeStamp",<your time stamp>);
```

Then you can just send the jsonObject to your server and save it there. TO send JSON to your server make a JsonObjectRequest call using volley library. You can implement volley by following the below link.

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html